# In Java, how do I paint a Rectangle two different Colors?

Tags: java, colors, jcomponent

I looked for this and could not find it anywhere. I have a RoundedRectangle2D Component that represents my health bar in a game, and when I call a subtractHealth method, I want it to proportionally paint a section of the rectangle red over the green, making it look like the health bar lost health. I previously had two rectangles, a green one and a red one, one behind the other, but I was told I should change this, and I agreed it would be one less bit of memory used, so does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Having two rectangles does seem like the way to go.

Comment: I think rectangle is about as basic as you get, not sure that a rectangle that is able to paint itself two different colours would be any different from 2 rectangles, or use less memory

Comment: You was told to change it to what ? As others said, you should stick to your previous plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the GradientPaint class. http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/graphics2D/gradient-paint.shtml

Comment: +1, probably wouldn't use less memory but would definitely look good (and I don't think a rectangle of memory is much to quibble over)

Comment: @dann.dev This [clip of Rasputina's "Rats"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIHwTMKj9PU&feature=plcp&context=C4e1091eVDvjVQa1PpcFNcyNNUmyAUN0WoThOVaCR7bPczt1XQMnc%3D) shows left/right volume using a semi transparent `GradientPaint` with a more solid border.  Quite nice (if I say so myself). ;)

Comment: Looks good, I did notice it tears a bit every now and then though, wonder if it's the painting method or the component?

Comment: It says the gradient gradually changes color at the middle section in between the two colors, is this true and/or is it possible to make this change absolute?